# Moving from Navigation controller to parent view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Using swift for doing the iphone app.  Have a button in parent view controller and a segue pointing to navigation controller .  When  button is clicked in parent view controller it goes to the navigation controller.  How do I have a back in navigation view controller to move it parent view controller when it's displaying navigation view controller?

Comment: change the `kind of segue`  to **push** then you should be alright...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your button to call `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`. This should dismiss the navigation controller that was presented.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. sorry for the delayed response

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to return from where you came from. In that case look into [Unwind Segues](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/). Essentially you a add method to the parent view controller with a specific signature you, then you can navigate back to it using interface builder or programatically.

Comment: Thx a lot for the info .  Issue is My First view controller is not inside navigation controller.    Create a manual segue to  a Navigation controller that has a list of view controllers.   Can I do this way or do i neet to move the first view controller inside the navigation controller?

Comment: You didn't mention how you instantiated the navigation controller.  So if you called  presentViewController:animated:completion:  to show the navigation controller then call [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; to dismiss it. Set up self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem to call this method in your Navigation Controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  Sorry for the delayed respone